# Dúvida requisição em branco webservice PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Estou com um problema em uma parte do código:

```
function obterBD($nome){

// Conecatar banco de dados
if(!$conn = connectBD()){
    return false;
}

// Incluir/Atualizar retorno no banco de dados
$arrayReturn = getnota($conn, $nome);

if(isset($arrayReturn['registros'])){
    return $arrayReturn;
}

$arrayReturn = array_merge(getmatricula($conn, $nome), $arrayReturn);

$arrayReturn = array_merge(getnomecompleto($conn, $nome), $arrayReturn);

// Encerra conexão com banco
closeBD($conn);

return $arrayReturn;

}
```

O página é o seguinte:

Faz uma requisição em um webservice e pega os dados. Acontece que as vezes não existe o "nomecompleto" e então é apresentado erro:

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in path on line 69 
$arrayReturn = array_merge(getnomecompleto($conn, $nome), $arrayReturn); --> Essa é a linha 69.
```

E se eu comento essa linha o erro desaparece. Como eu coloco para que se não conseguir pegar o nome completo, escreva algo do tipo: "Não disponível" ?

Comment: Na funcao `getnomecompleto` retorne um array vazio ou um array com a posição vazia.

Comment: @Everson, uma array vazio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valide o valor retornado antes de chamar o array_merge como no exemplo abaixo. Ou siga a orientação do @Everson de alterar a função getnomecompleto() e retornar um array vazio ou um array com um item 'Não disponível'.

```
$nome_completo = getnomecompleto($conn, $nome);
$nome_completo = is_array($nome_completo) ? $nome_completo : array('Não disponível');
$arrayReturn = array_merge($nome_completo, $arrayReturn);
```